# what is a substitute for margin-bottom in outlook emails

Tags: html, css, outlook, margin, padding

I have a bottom margin for several divs in an outlook email template. However it doesn't work,is there any way over coming this?

Thanks!

Comment: You will find some nice tips in this article: https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/outlookcom-margins/

Comment: Do you happen to know how to set the background color in outlook so it appears in the whole window.... and centers the message ?

Comment: Elina - We should not mix subjects in the questions... It may misslead people who are looking for the same problem. You should post anoter question with your specific issue. We'll be glad to help!

Comment: Sorry about that -  I am new to stack overflow, and still getting used to it - I have posted another question here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275221/how-to-centre-a-html-email-in-outlook-and-make-the-background-color-filled

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Using tables and cellspacing with combinations cellpadding